# Escape special characters in a filename

Tags: php, .htaccess, escaping

We have inherited a system whereby file uploads were originally allowed using the filename of the original file - we now create a hash and rename all uploads but there are around 20,000 legacy files which contain mostly + and () in the filename e.g. bob_smith(2).doc

We are passing all files through an htaccess rewriterule and any which contain those characters give an error - it isn't a viable option to manually change all the filenames and the corresponding database column for the file manually so how can we escape those characters at runtime so the rewrite rule still works?

Current rewriterule is:

```
RewriteRule ^view/([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)\.php /documents/view.php?doc=$1 [L]
```

Comment: they are uploading the file via php right ?

Comment: Write a script, which takes those files, renames them according to your rules and updates records in db.

Comment: @Ido - they were originally, this is only for legacy files. For new files we used hashed names using the original filename, time and the user ID

Comment: @Cheery Longer term that is what I want to do using regex to find those files affected but short term I was hoping for something which would allow us to stick a plaster over it

Comment: @bhttoan then show your rewrite rules to see the reason of the problem.

Comment: Unless you want to put the client (and the server) through multiple redirects -- one for each character replaced, I suggest that you re-evaluate your solution to the issue.  

It seems that changing the file names directly would be the route to go, instead of attempting to rewrite each URL multiple times.

Comment: `(` and `)` should be URL encoded, so you have to add to the rule `%` symbol, I think. And in `view.php` you have to do all the actions listed above to rename the file, so that there will be no another redirect by the real name.